# Calculate size of pixel array of image using RGBA32 pixel format

Tags: image, pixel

I have a simple image that stores the width, height, pixelformat, and some other things that I'm not sure about, and then followed by the pixel data.

I've been told the pixel format is RGBA32, and that the rest of the data is just the pixel data.

What's the formula for calculating it?
From my understanding, 8 bits are required for each of the RGBA colors, so 4 bytes are required for each pixel.

So then I would conclude the size of the pixel array is width * height * 4, but that wasn't enough.

Comment: How do you know that wasn't enough? Why don't you post the extra data that you have?

Comment: Who / what is providing you this image? If this is a specific image format, I would guess that there is possibly some kind of header or checksum or metadata or comments.

Comment: I have width and height of 64 * 64  and total pixel data size of 21760. When I read 21760 bytes and display it, it looks fine. When I only read 64 * 64 * 4, it's wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? The first 10 bytes or so should be particularly critical as if it is a standard image format, there is likely a header.

Comment: I reverse binary formats but I've never done image formats so this image was provided by a friend as a "training" format since it's supposed to be a really easy format. The header simply starts with two integers for the width and height, along with 3 other integers that are just -1's, followed by the pixel data. I think he just quickly threw something together. I imagine there's a simple formula to use to figure out the size of the data I need to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 64px by 64px BMP with RGBA32 will typically be 16440 bytes (presuming BITMAPV3INFOHEADER). 56 bytes for the header, 16384 bytes for the pixel data (which is 64*64*4). The [header size can vary though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_.28bitmap_information_header.29) and be as large as 124 bytes (BITMAPV5HEADER) presuming a standard BMP.

I would guess that you've got one or more of the following to account for your extra ~5376 (21760 - 16384) bytes:

- Integrity check(s) (checksum, CRC, etc)
- A longer header than you currently assume
- Pixel alignment which isn't 4 bytes
- Metadata (comments, EXIF data, GPS data, etc)
- ICC Color Profile
- A data gap

In any case, I would first check the **last** 16384 (64 * 64 * 4) bytes of data which is likely where your image data is (if this format at all takes after the BMP format and doesn't have some trailing metadata or ICC profile or integrity check). On a side note, RGBA data is typically stored with the alpha byte first (ARGB).

Might be worth taking a look at this [diagram of the BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBMPfileFormat.png) just to familiarize yourself with a common image format's structure.